# Esiste la parola soggefazione?

Tags: word-meaning

Il traduttore di Google (non ridete, a volte è comodo usarlo) mi ha tradotto "subfigures" con "soggefazioni".

Non ho mai sentito questa parola, né la trovo su internet: esiste o il traduttore di Google ogni tanto ci mette anche dell'inventiva?

La frase completa era questa:

> I'm preparing a manuscript for a journal where they tend to have the
>   caption over-print on the image for subfigures to really squeeze out
>   all the whitespace in these panels (Here's an example document, please
>   look at the PDF: https://elifesciences.org/articles/39777).
>
> So, I've been trying to remove whitespaces around my subfigures too. I
>   used a negative skip in the subcaption set up which brings the
>   subcaption nearer to the image. However, when using this "hack", in a
>   majority of cases, the image prints over the label. Is it possible to
>   do it the other way around: get the subcaption label to over-print on
>   the image?

da un [post di TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481538/how-does-one-get-the-caption-to-over-print-an-image/490277#490277), ma adesso "soggefazione" non mi esce più, mi lascia subfigure (nel primo paragrafo) e mi traduce sottofigure (nel secondo).

Comment: Esiste sicuramente soggezione, per subfigures a me Google dà sotto figure... Io userei didascalie, equivalente di caption

Comment: È curioso, ma neanche il mio Google Translate capisce cosa significhi "soggefazione" in italiano.

Comment: Ogni tanto anche a me compaiono parole inventate in Google Translate. Ipotizzo che sia dovuto al fatto che non si limita a tradurre parola per parola, né a riprendere frammenti di frasi preesistenti, ma funziona anche con un qualche sistema di deep learning che di fatto “ragiona” (fra moltissime virgolette) in modi “originali” (di nuovo), anche mettendo insieme pezzi di parole e simili.

Comment: A me dà *sottofigure* https://translate.google.it/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=it&text=subfigures

Comment: @egreg Probabilmente dipende dalla frase, non ho tradotto la parola singola.

Comment: Quindi... è quasi sicuro che si tratta di una parola inventata da Google Translate, no? (non si trova da nessuna parte, @DaG ha visto altre parole inventate da questo software...).

Comment: @charo Sì, a questo punto mi pare sicuro! Sinceramente, non ne sono molto contenta.

Comment: @abarisone Non ho tradotto la parola singola, era in una frase, per cui Google ci ha messo del suo.

Comment: @CarLaTeX puoi inserire la frase che stavi tentando di tradurre?

Comment: @DaG Non mi era mai capitato, ma così rischiano di fare danni...

Comment: @abarisone L'ho inserita, ma ora il traduttore non mi dà più "soggefazione".

Comment: Potresti scrivere tu stessa la risposta alla domanda?

Comment: @charo Aspetto un po' prima di farlo, magari DaG o abarisone vogliono rispondere.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Google Translate fa già grossi danni, se non viene usato con estrema cautela: tu giustamente ti sei posta il problema, ma c'è chi lo prende per oro colato, e addirittura lo usa per imparare una lingua straniera.

Comment: @DaG Infatti! In genere rileggo e confronto sempre quello che traduce in automatico, perché alcune volte vengono fuori cose che non stanno né in cielo né in terra :)

Comment: Usa un giro di parole: Riquadro, vignetta, I, II, III immagine dell'illustrazione. Se proprio non ti trovi, riporta il termine straniero

Comment: @DDS Grazie, in realtà il problema non è tradurre "subfigure" ma la parola che si è inventato Google per farlo :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Insisto, potresti scrivere tu stessa la risposta alla domanda?

Comment: @Charo Fatto, ciao!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La parola "soggefazione" non esiste.

Come ha ipotizzato DaG, ogni tanto il traduttore di Google si inventa le parole in base ad un qualche suo algoritmo di "intelligenza artificiale".

Consiglio a tutti di controllare le traduzioni automatiche prima di utilizzarle.